# vector iterator not dereferncable....?

Tags: vector, iterator

`void calc_distance(vector fingerTips, CvPoint palmCenter,IplImage *source)
{
    double distance = 0;

```
vector<CvPoint>::iterator p;

if (fingerTips.size() != NULL && fingerTips.size() <= 5 && fingerTips.size()  >= 1)
{   

    if ((fingerTips.size() > 1) || (fingerTips.size() <= 5))
        {

        distance = 0;

        p = fingerTips.begin();

        CvPoint forefinger = *p;

        CvPoint secondfinger;

        for( ;p != fingerTips.end(); )
                    {

                           p++; 

                           secondfinger = *p;

               distance +=  sqrt(double((forefinger.x - secondfinger.x) *
```

(forefinger.x - secondfinger.x) + (forefinger.y - secondfinger.y) * (forefinger.y - secondfinger.y)) );

```
                cvLine(source,forefinger,secondfinger,cvScalar(1.0,1.0,1.0),3,8);

                forefinger = secondfinger;

            }
                    }
     }
```

}

//as parameters i passed the the vector of fingertips co-ordinate and the center of the palm along with image source
but still im getting the error: "vector iterator not differefercable"....
the error occurs in the 2nd iteration at  " secondfinger = *p;" line.....
please help me.....

here i am trying to get distance between each fingers and summing each of the them to get 
the final distance....

please help me...

Answer (score 1):

You check `p != end`, then `P++`, then dereference. You should just do a standard for loop:

```
for(; p != fingerTips.end(); p++)
{
    //p++ //This is gone now. It's up in the for loop
   ...
}
```

instead of having `p++` in your for loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to dereference `p` before you increment it; otherwise, you end up trying to dereference `fingertips.end()` when you get to the end of the collection, which cannot be dereferenced.

```
for( ;p != fingerTips.end(); ++p)
{
    secondfinger = *p;

    distance +=  sqrt(double((forefinger.x - secondfinger.x) * (forefinger.x - secondfinger.x) + (forefinger.y - secondfinger.y) * (forefinger.y - secondfinger.y)) );

    cvLine(source,forefinger,secondfinger,cvScalar(1.0,1.0,1.0),3,8);

    forefinger = secondfinger;

}
```